# Djando tempus dominus modal does not work

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have installed in my app the `tempus_dominus` app, usuing in the following manner:

```
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker, TimePicker, DateTimePicker

class InformazioniGeneraliForm(forms.ModelForm):
    data_registrazione=forms.DateTimeField(widget=DatePicker(attrs={
                'append': 'fa fa-calendar',
                'icon_toggle': True,
            }))
```

And in my template utilized in the following manner:

```
{{ form.media }}
<div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                     {{form.codice_commessa|as_crispy_field}}
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                     {{form.data_registrazione|as_crispy_field}}
                 </div>
```

All works great but now I have the necessity to insert a modal button in the same page. I have tried to insert the same `{{form.data_registrazione|as_crispy_field}}` but when I press the datepicker it opens the first form one like in the following photo:

[image]

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: That's probably a CSS change that you'll require to add to the Datepicker's class. You have to increase the `z-index` value of the calendar widget to make it appear above the modal.

Comment: Could you make me an example with my code?

Comment: The css code is probably from the 3rd party package tempus-dominus-datetimepicker.
After checking the docs, the css class is probably `bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget`. Can you confirm this using console? You can see how to change z-index here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index